# how to change link from image url using php

Tags: php

i want to get image from google plus, url image like here

```
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-Sjhjjjjjj/........./s200-c/201gjghjphotoo1.jpg
```

how to can replace `s200-c` to `s0` for full size

my code but not work

```
$file = preg_replace("/.+\\/\\/(\\d+).+/", "s0", $file);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) function can do the trick.

`$file = str_replace("s200-c", "s0", $file);`